# Can the controller of a modal window access functions in parent controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-bootstrap

Suppose you launch a modal window using $modal.open from within an angular directive.

Does the modal window have access to functions defined with the parent directive?

Directive controller code

```
..
function parentFunction()
{
     return 5;
}

$scope.showDialog = function()
{
     var dialog = $modal.open({
     controller: 'modalController',
     ...
}
```

'modalController' code

`var val = parentFunction();`

Comment: what do you mean by "the modal window" in referring to having access. Do you mean the controller of the modal window?

Comment: Yes i do mean the controller of the modal window. Made the changes to the question

Comment: "Does the modal window have access to functions defined with the parent directive?"  Do you mean parent scope here?

Comment: I am talking about regular functions defined with the parent directive and not functions which are defined as $scope.functionName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't have lexical scope access, but there are 2 ways (that I know of) to "pass data" to the controller, depending on what makes more sense to you:

**1) via `$scope`:**

```
$scope.parentFn = function parentFn(){
};

var dialog = $modal.open({
     controller: 'modalController',
     scope: $scope,
     //...
});
```

**2) via `resolve`:**

```
function parentFn(){
}

var dialog = $modal.open({
     controller: 'modalController',
     resolve: {
       parentFn: function(){
         return parentFn;
       }
     },
     // ...
});
```

then you could get `parentFn` as a local injectable into the `modalController`:

```
.controller("modalController", function(parentFn){
   parentFn();
});
```

### Or...

if you defined your controller inline, then it would have lexical scope access:

```
function parentFn(){
}

var dialog = $modal.open({
     controller: function modalController(){
        parentFn();
     },
     // ...
});
```

Comment: Via resolve when you inject parentFn when i try to call this function inside another function in modal controlle.

Comment: @user3722785, I'm unclear on what you're asking/saying